# How can I share data between non parent-child components in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have 3 components (get-users, get-projects, get-tasks) - each contains a button which fires an ajax request to retreive some data. I want the data returned from the ajax request to be displayed in a fourth independent component on the page (show-results).  e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6>
        <get-users></get-users>
        <get-projects></get-projects>
        <get-tasks></get-tasks>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6>
        <show-results></show-results>
    </div>
</div>
```

The get-users component:

```
<script>
export default {
    template: require('./get_users.template.html'),

    data: function() {
        return {
            userList: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getUsers(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

               this.$http.get('api/getusers').then(function (response) {
                    this.userList = response.data.users;   // How can I also pass this to the show-results component?         
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The Vue instance/decalaration

```
var Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

import getUsers  from './components/get_users.vue';
import getProjects  from './components/get_projects.vue';
import getTasks  from './components/get_tasks.vue';
import showResults  from './components/show_results.vue';


   new Vue ({
    el: '#app',

    components: { GetUsers, GetProjects, GetTasks, ShowResults },

})
```

As the show-results component isn't a part of a parent/child relationship I cant use the $broadcast or $dispatch methods of the API.

Is it possible to pass the data from one component to another at the completion of the ajax promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: this answer is only valid for vue 1**

You could do a broadcast from the root Vue instance for example. `this.$root` gives you access to the root component in your current vue instance. Thus it will reach at its children:

```
<script>
export default {
    template: require('./get_users.template.html'),

    data: function() {
        return {
            userList: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getUsers(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

               this.$http.get('api/getusers').then(function (response) {
                    this.userList = response.data.users;
                    this.$root.broadcast('show-results:users', { users: response.data.users });
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Then you listen for the `show-results:users` event in your `show-results` component:

```
events: {
    'show-results:users': function(data) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Of course you can give the event any name you want to.

Answer (score 12):

With Vue 2.0 things are bit different as broadcast has been deprecated.
[Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) talks about using centralized event bus to accomplish this. Here's how you could it;

1. Define centralized event hub. So in your The Vue instance/decalaration define

   ```
    const eventHub = new Vue() // Single event hub

    // Distribute to components using global mixin
    Vue.mixin({
        data: function () {
            return {
                eventHub: eventHub
            }
        }
    })
   ```
2. Now in your component you can emit events with

   ```
    this.eventHub.$emit('show-results:users', { users: response.data.users })
   ```
3. And to listen you do

   ```
    this.eventHub.$on('show-results:users', data => {
    // do your thing
    })
   ```

Comment: sorry i'm new to vue and wanting to solve this problem in vue 2.  could you expand a bit on what you're doing?

Comment: nm, i found this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: Is "show-results:" just a part of event name or this is something vue-specific syntax?

Comment: Just part of event name.

Comment: This doesn't sync the data across components tho right? Just passes the data?

Comment: @Owen it's passing the data whenever $emit is triggered

Comment: This is perfect. Pass the data and I'll sync myself

Answer (score 3):

Use this small [plugin](https://github.com/mudin/vue-global-var) if you want to share data between a lot of nested components:

```
Vue.use(VueGlobalVariable, {
  globals: {
    user: new User('testuser'),
    ....
  },
});
```

use `$user` in any component!

Comment: I used this library just now and it's really helpful for easy using