# Share data across different components in Vuejs

Tags: model, components, vue.js

Given the mini Vuejs app down below.

When I click one of my increment/decrement buttons, the value within the "counter" component updates but the value inside "alphabet" doesn't.
Any ideas on how can I share the same data across those two components so that they automatically update ?

```js
var counter = Vue.extend({
    props: ['start'],
    template: '#counter',
    data: function() {
      return {
        value: this.start
      }
    },
    methods: {
      increment: function() {
        this.value++
      },
      decrement: function() {
        this.value--
      }
    }
  });

  var alphabet = Vue.extend({
    props: ['value'],
    template: '#alphabet',
    data: function() {
      return {
        value: 0
      }
    }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      val: 5
    },
    components: {
      counter: counter,
      alphabet: alphabet
    }
  });
```

```html
<script id="counter" type="text/template">
  <button @click="increment">+</button> {{ value }}
  <button @click="decrement">-</button>
</script>
<script id="alphabet" type="text/template"> {{ value }} </script>
<div id="app">
  <counter :start="val"></counter>
  <alphabet :value="val"></alphabet>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share data between non parent-child components in Vue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925841/how-can-i-share-data-between-non-parent-child-components-in-vue)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were 2 issues with the way you set it up.  Here it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/j9hua7c8/

First issue was in the `counter` component, you created a new variable called `value` and it a value of `this.start`.  This took the value of `start` and assigned it to `value`, but since `value` was a new variable it was no longer sync'd to `start`. Updated version:

```
var counter = Vue.extend({
  props: ['value'],
  template: '#counter',
  methods: {
    increment: function() {this.value++},
    decrement: function() {this.value--}
  }
});
```

Second thing is, in order to have a child variable sync two-ways, you need to use the `.sync` modifier on the binding.  By default, they are only one-way bindings. Updated:

```
<counter :value.sync="val"></counter>
```

You can also use [$dispatch](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-dispatch) and [$broadcast](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-broadcast) to communicate between parent and child components if that is better for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices.

#### 1 Manually sync your values

in your `increment` and `decrement` functions add this sentence

```
this.$parent.val = this.value;
```

and make your alphabet value equal to the parent val

```
computed: {
    value: function() {
        return this.$parent.val;
    }
  }
```

resulting in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv57po7s/1/)

#### 2 Use [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) to keep a global state of your data

With `vuex` you can `store` a common `state` for all your components. This state will be reactive, so will be updated for every component when you change its value. This could be an overkill for your use case, but is definitly a choice to keep in mind

Comment: So based on the above is it correct to say that Vuejs is mostly for creating isolated components? The first choice is not really ideal, whereas the second on relies on another framework.

Comment: Vuejs is for making reactive SPA. If you need extended functionality you can use a set of plugins such as vue-resource, for handlingd server interaction, vue router for routes, and vuex for state management. This is similar to how other frameworks work, in fact, vuex is inspired in flux and redux, for react

Comment: @skay Vue is great for this type of stuff and you don't need any other extensions, this functionality is built in. See my answer.

Comment: @jeff Yeap, I agree - something as simple as that shouldn't require any extensions.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned before, you can use vuex. However, you don't *have* to use vuex. Vuex merely helps enforce a convention of how to use a global state, and tries to make it hard to to do the wrong thing.

However, with a little self-discipline, you can easily do it yourself. Just make global object and pass that on to all your components in their data function.

Comment: There is no need to use a global object, it can just be a property of the parent component that is sync'd to the child components

Answer (score 1):

It took me a long while of digging to come to the conclusion I needed **[VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)** to have *components* talk to one another. So I am recommending to everyone, start learning *VueX* now so you do not waste time. Your co-workers will appreciate the code standards, and will recognize *VueX* as the preferred approach. I will admit, I read through every page of the *VueX* website documentation today, and I was still for lack of a working example. However, I did find the [VueX Module Decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-module-decorators) page earlier, and I will be implementing this myself as I did enjoy, [Vue Class Component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component), and [Vue Property Decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) packages when I transitioned to **Typescript** with Vue.

I initially used *Vue Component* code such as `this.$children` or `this.$parent.$children` in **JavaScript** to loop through *components* to get to *component data* and call *methods* on other *components* to setup page *state* how I needed. I will say this is a *dirty* approach, but it works if you need something quick. I say it's *dirty*, because all *Vue Components* have an **isolated** scope. The *methods* I was creating to access data from **outside** the *components*, were only ever meant to be accessed from **within** the *component itself* or from the *component's template* from a *VueJS* standpoint. However, JavaScript was allowing me to get away with what I was doing, because I knew the structure of the *DOM*. If you are out of luck with everything you've seen, and you are days in on a project, and are in dire need something at all; here is a working example of what I am referring to: (Dirty Approach)[https://jsfiddle.net/OhRyanOh/s5b21hym/].

If you use the `Dirty Approach`, e.g. surfing `this.$children` or `this.$parent.$children`; please refactor your application later and swap to `VueX`. I was using this `unit-test-driver` component to fill out the form elements *"for me"*, so I could build the application faster, testing along the way. I was copying and pasting data from Word/Excel, and needed to dynamically add new form components, and then fill those with data, and generate a `pretty XML` to the clipboard. I had many erros as I was learning *Vue* components for the first time when I wrote the `Dirty Approach` code. It was becoming very combersome to get to the point of being able to test and I was copying and pasting way too much from another document, which is why I created the `unit-test-driver` component to speed me along in development. I have since then transitioned all this to a [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) based project to **TypeScript**, and wound up with a broken `unit-test-driver` implementation due to `this.$refs`, `this.$props`, and *Vue's* *isolated component scope*. I wish I had just known to startout with *VueX*, and in writing all this, hopefully I save someone else valuable time.

After transitioning my application to **TypeScript**, was when I realized `this.$parent` or `this.$children` members do not play so nice with `type saftey`, and so my application was broken and I couldn't easily cast to `TypeScript` components from *DOM* *Elements*. I do not like using type `<any>` anywhere in `TypeScript`, as this introduces `union types` like `<string | null | undefined>`, and dependent code will be responsible for extra undefined/null checks for `type safety` and you start loosing value guarantees. Here are relevent links: [Basic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) *(check for `--strictNullChecks`)*, [Douglous Crockford Vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0&feature=youtu.be&t=9m21s), [Null and Undefined](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/null-undefined.html).

I needed to find another way for *component communication*. I tried using `this.$refs` instead as it is a best practice for accessing *DOM* *Elements*, and then lost access to calling functions on the child components... even after `this.$nextTick(...)` in `mounted(): Promise<void>`. I also tried the `this.$props` approach, however is not valid for sharing data between *components*, but more of a hand me down of data to children through binding data in attributes, in the *component template* tag. I also went down the road of the *Dodo*, newing up my own *TypeScript Vue Components* and passing arround arrays of self instantiated components, only to learn that when iterating over an array with `v-for`, that *Vue* had it's own game plan, and had also instantiated it's own *components* for each row in the arrays as well. The *self-referenced components* I created and linked, did not contain the same data as the *DOM components*, because *Vue* did not use the items in *my arrays of components I self-instantiated*, regardless of me self assinging their arrays and values to `this.$refs`, and every combination in between. If you are using a new operator for your own components that need to be displayed in the *DOM*, it's a bad design choice. I should be able to accomplish everything I'm doing with *Isolated Scopes* and *Shared Global Component State* through *VueX* instead. Resort to `this.$props` to pass initialization values to *child components*, otherwise use *VueX* for *Shared Component State*.

My last approach before I figured out what *VueX* was, left with the *global bus* approach, and that is just not elegant for larger applications due to *development time* and *complexity*. This concept is also documented on the *VueJS* [Component Edge Cases](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance) page, under the heading **Accessing the Root Instance**, where it is then stated with a followup point: `"This can be convenient for demos or very small apps with a handful of components. However, the pattern does not scale well to medium or large-scale applications, so we strongly recommend using Vuex to manage state in most cases."`

Anyways, I'm back off to figuring out *VueX* myself now for my own implementation. Perhaps I can edit this later with a better *VueJs/TypeScript* example. I do not have one for the time being, and there may be one out there by now. My hesitance was that there wasn't clean *TypeScript VueX* examples, when I was first looking and I didn't know my scenario usage for it right away, so I avoided it like the plague... only to then get completely stumped out of my gourd on why I had undefined functions on my *components*, I was trying to get data out of through `this.$refs` after `mount/nextTick` lol [Mount/NextTick](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/nexttick-in-mounted-not-working-for-waiting-on-component-render/29952/4). Yeah, I definitely needed *VueX*, especially going *TypeScript*.