# How to share data between components in VueJS

Tags: vue-component, vue-router, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a fairly simple VueJS app, 3 components (Login, SelectSomething, DoStuff)

Login component is just a form for user and pass input while the second component needs to display some data obtained in the login progress.

How can I share data from one component to the others? So that when I route to second component I still have the data obtained in the Login one?

Comment: Have you read the section in the Vue guid on [state management](https://vuejs.org/guide/state-management.html)?

Comment: Not yet, but it looks like what I need. Guess that is what happens when you are to eager to start developing before finishing to read the whole documentation.

Comment: Hi there! If you found my answer accurate (and helpful), please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @PatrickSteele 's answer is what I was looking for but he added it as a comment which I can't "accept". With your answer I can only pass data to child components and not sibling components. Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share data between non parent-child components in Vue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925841/how-can-i-share-data-between-non-parent-child-components-in-vue)

Answer (score 23):

You can either use [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props) or an event bus, where you'll be able to emit an event from a component and listen on another

```
vm.$on('test', function (msg) {
  console.log(msg)
})

vm.$emit('test', 'hi')
// -> "hi"
```

Answer (score 13):

In Vue.js components can communicate with each other using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) or [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Events). It all depends on the relation between your components.

Let's take this small example:

```
<template>
<h2>Parent Component</h2>
<child-component></child-component>
</template>
```

To send information from the parent to Child, you will need to use props:

```
<template>
<h2>Parent Component</h2>
<child-component :propsName="example"></child-component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data(){
  return{
   example: 'Send this variable to the child'
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

To send information from the child to the parent, you will need to use events:

Child Component

```
<script>
 ...
 this.$emit('example', this.variable);
</script>
```

Parent Component

```
<template>
<h2>Parent Component</h2>
<child-component @example="methodName"></child-component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 methods: {
  methodName(variable){
   ...
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Check the documentation of vue.js for more information about this subject. This is a very brief introduction.

Answer (score 4):

Use this small [plugin](https://github.com/mudin/vue-global-var) if you have a lot of nested components:

```
Vue.use(VueGlobalVariable, {
  globals: {
    user: new User('user1'),
    obj:{},
    config:Config,
    ....
  },
});
```

Now you can use `$user` in any component without using props or other