# Binding value of one component to another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two separate components. In one component, I have an input, and on another component I want have a variable that is always equal to the input value. I don't want to bind it an event which will limit me to that event; I want to constantly watching it. Thus, I thought `$emit` is not a good option.

What is the appropriate way of achieving this?

```
Vue.component('first', {
    data: {
       helloVal: "Hello world"
    }
    template: `
        <div>
           <input :hello="helloVal">
        </div>
    `
})


Vue.component('first', {
    template: `
        <div>
           <p>{{ helloVal }}</p>
        </div>
    `
})
```

How can I make `hello` to always be equal to `helloVal`? Can I use `v-model:` between separate components?

Comment: Event bus is the way to go here: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/104/

Comment: `v-model` is just a sugar for `v-bind` + `v-on` pair, the underlying mechanics are exactly the same as with explicit events. Why do you think `$emit` is bad anyway?

Comment: Because initially, I need to set data to a vanilla javascript variable (that comes from Laravel) - like `var helloStr = {{ $input }} ; data: { hello = helloStr }`. If I want to use, I need to bind an event, such as click or change. I thought it won't trigger the $emit on initialisation because event won't be triggered. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can emit an event with initially hardcoded text on initial load: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/105/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between components in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224345/how-to-share-data-between-components-in-vuejs)