# Pass data from Header-component to Search-page in Laravel, Vue, Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

So, I'm pretty new to Vue and trying to figure out how to pass data between components. I have a search bar/form in my Header Component where I do a axios-request to get data from the SearchController. Now, how do I pass that data to my Search.vue file/template? This is my structure.

**Search.vue**

```
<MainLayout>
     Search results to be displayed here
</MainLayout>
```

**MainLayout.vue**

```
<template>
     <Header></Header>
     <slot></slot>
     <!-- Rest of layout -->
</template>
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
     <form>
         <!-- My form fields stuff -->
     </form>
     <script>
         <!-- My axios request/response to/from SearchController -->
     </script>
</template>
```

So now how do I send the data from the Header.vue over to Search.vue so I can print the results on that page?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224345/how-to-share-data-between-components-in-vuejs

Comment: @RatebHabbab Thanks, figured it out. Didn't know about the $emit thing.