# How split vue single components template section in to smaller subtemplates

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

My application is being build on vuejs@2 has multiple forms most of the share same html template with add and reset button. As well as same method, resetForm nullifies the "item" property and resets the form, and create method sends the item to the backend.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="action">
        <button class="btn btn-white" @click="create()">&#9998; Add</button>
        <button class="btn btn-white" @click="resetForm()">&#x274C; Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can share methods via mixins with each component but I can't share "template partial" same way. How to you approach such scenario?

I tried to create component create-reset-buttons, but I have no way to trigger parent method as each component encapsulates its functionality and does not allow to modify props from the child. Which need to be done in order to reset the parent form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components are not allowed to modify the props, but there are [ways](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) child can communicate to parent as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915910/1610034) in detail.

> In Vue.js, the parent-child component relationship can be summarized as props down, events up. The parent passes data down to the child via props, and the child sends messages to the parent via events. Let’s see how they work next.

[image]

### [How to pass props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props)

Following is the code to pass props to chile element:

```
<div>
  <input v-model="parentMsg">
  <br>
  <child v-bind:my-message="parentMsg"></child>
</div>
```

### [How to emit event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events)

HTML:

```
<div id="counter-event-example">
  <p>{{ total }}</p>
  <button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
  <button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  template: '<button v-on:click="increment">{{ counter }}</button>',
  data: function () {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function () {
      this.counter += 1
      this.$emit('increment')
    }
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: '#counter-event-example',
  data: {
    total: 0
  },
  methods: {
    incrementTotal: function () {
      this.total += 1
    }
  }
})
```