# How to pass data from child to parent component in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.Js where i am calling my child component multiple times from parent. Which means there are separate instance created for all the different call. Data "json" will contain seperate value for all the different instance.
Now i want to fetch data present in variable json in all the instance of child component from parent component.

```
[Code]
Parent component
<div v-for="(value, index) in inputs" :key="index++">
     <ChildComponent :componentcount="index" ></ChildComponent>
</div>

Child Component
<template>
    <div id="hello">
        <div>
            <v-text-field :id="'ComponentHeader_' + $attrs.componentcount" v-model="header" 
                 class="headertag" label="Child Tag" @change="createJson" outlined>
            </v-text-field>       
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
          json:"",
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data from child to parent in Vuejs (is it so complicated?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334796/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-in-vuejs-is-it-so-complicated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use $emit method for this purpose.
v-on directive captures the child components events that is emitted by $emit

Child component triggers clicked event:

export default {
  methods: {
    onClickButton (event) {
      this.$emit('clicked', 'someValue')
    }
  }
}
Parent component receive clicked event:

<div>
  <child @clicked="onClickChild"></child>
</div>
export default {
  methods: {
    onClickChild (value) {
      console.log(value) // someValue
    }
  }
}
```