# How to dynamically display an image in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dynamic-image-generation

Please see here the relations between components
[How to pass value from one child component to another in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59855921/1745902)

The snippet bellow not giving an error and not displaying the image

```
<img v-bind:src="image_url" />
```

Code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-bind:src="image_url" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["image_url"]
};
</script>
```

**image_url** comes from another component and in VueJS developer's tool I was able to confirm the value is an url. Looks like something wrong with the way how I'm trying to render a dynamic  image.

[image]

Comment: what does your file structure look like?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have updated my post. The code structure can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/q/59855921/1745902

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493036/3462319

Comment: It looks like it's showing how to render for multiple images, where in my case I'm dealing with one URL in the ItemImage component. Maybe I could use that answer as hint. I will try. I'm new to VueJS.

Comment: also that post is from 2016. I believe this can be done in a better way these days...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to expose your images to your web server. Hopefully Vue-cli does that for you. You have to move your assets folder from src to the public folder.

More info on https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

Answer (score 0):

Might worked on yours. Make a watcher for that to update again the props value an rerender it in your component.

```
export default {
  props: ["image_url"],
  watch: {
          image_url(val){
              this.image_url = val
          },
    }

};
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please add more explanation how to add it and where?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add.

```
<div v-if="image_url">
  <img v-bind:src="image_url" />
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note image urls typically begin with a forward slash. /assets/images/apple.jpg

Comment: Thanks. Adding the snippet and slashes in the url didn't help

Comment: Double check the image exists in your assets/images folder.

Comment: Images are there. When I tried explicitly specify one url, it worked. So something wrong with how I'm trying to render

Comment: Inspect the element in dev tools. Is there a path to the image in the src.