# How to pass data back and forth in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm entirely new to Vue, and I've been coding for weeks now. I'm not so sure if I'm doing this right, but this is how I transfer data from one component to another:

[image]

The red arrow flow works, but I don't know how to send data in the green arrow after processing the red arrow data in the connection component.

What I want is to trigger a click event in the run test component (red box) and then send data to the connection component (green box) for processing. After the processing completes, the connection component then sends data back to the run test component to update the status.

Comment: The simple solution is to use custom global eventbus, [example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus)

Or you can use vuex which is the state management plugin for vue.js [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) , I know it can be overwhelming when you are begginner.

Comment: Did you see the red arrow from `Run Test` to `index page`, you can do the same. i.e create a event in the parent component and emit it from the child. see this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334796/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-in-vuejs-is-it-so-complicated#answers-header

Comment: other solutions: 1: `event bus`, 2: emit/listen on `$root`, 3: uses `vuex`.

Comment: @Sphinx is right - those are all suitable solutions. But in the end you probably will find out how much easier everything is with Vuex.

Comment: I would suggest you to take some time and learn Vuex. It will make it much more easier.