# Send data variable from child to parent using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a modal component (child called `modal_form.vue`), which I call inside another component called `index.vue`

I would like to send a data variable from `modal_form.vue` to `index.vue`.

Can someone give me an example?

PS: `modal_form` contains an axios request, so I would like to send the response to `index.vue`

**-- modal --**

```js
methods: {
    post() {
        getAPI.post('api/contact/', this.form)
        .then(response => (this.data = response.data))
        .then(() => (this.$emit('dataLoaded', this.data)))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response))
    }
}
```

**-- index --**

```js
<addContactModal v-if="openContactModal" :dataLoaded="refreshContactList"></addContactModal>

data: function(){
    return {
        openContactModal: true,
        contacts: []
    }
},
methods: {
    refreshContactList(data){
        this.contacts = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( data ) )
    },
}
```

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/43334946/8826120

Comment: @Vpa is there anyway to do it without an event listener, because i want to send the the data variable from modal to index.vue after getting my axios response

Comment: You can use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: @MohammadMomeni can you give an example please

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43334796/2815635

Comment: i don't want to use an event listener like click :(

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi I updated my answer considering your updated question codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use **custom events** to emit from a child component to a parent component in Vue.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

1. The example below shows **modal_form.vue** containing a single button that upon click runs the method **grabDataAndEmit**.
2. **grabDataAndEmit** makes an axios call using ES8 await syntax. The response is then stored in a variable and emitted to the parent via this code segment `this.$emit( 'handle-form-data', response );`.
3. You can see the parent **index.vue** handles the event in this code segment `@handle-form-data="handleFormDataCallback"` where **@handle-form-data** is the event being listened for, and the value passed in is the handler/callback for that event.

**Note:** @ is just an abbreviated version of v-on:

```html
<!-- modal_form.vue  -->
<template>
    <div>
        <div @click="grabDataAndEmit">button</div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    methods: {
        async grabDataAndEmit() {
            const response = await axios.get('/api/some/data');
            this.$emit( 'handle-form-data', response );
        }
    }
}
</script>

<!-- index.vue  -->
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- @handleFormData listens for "handleFormData" event to be $emit from the child.  -->
        <modal-form @handle-form-data="handleFormDataCallback" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import ModalForm from './modal_form.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    components: { ModalForm },
    methods: {
        handleFormDataCallback( $event ) {
            // Do something with the $event data emitted.
            // $event in this case is equal to "response" from the child component.
            console.log( $event )
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I hope this answer gives some help to your task at hand!

Comment: i used your code the only issue i still have is i try to refresh contacts variable, i  did this.contacts = $event.     but my v-for contact in contacts. not refreshed

Comment: can you help me by updating my contacts    variable , i already did,   this.contacts = $event      but my v-for  not refreshed

Comment: Hmm, i assume your $event is an array of objects? Maybe try doing `this.contacts =  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( $event ) )`.

Comment: same issue, i will update my question like that you can see my code ;)

Comment: Fixed i had : instead of @

Comment: change `:dataLoaded` to `@dataLoaded`.
Also you can handle the response in the first callback like so 
```
getAPI.post('api/contact/', this.form)
.then(response => { 
    this.data = response.data;
    this.$emit( 'dataLoaded', response.data ) 
})
.catch(error => console.log(error.response))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `$emit` and events there is a easier way with using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).
You should define your store like below guides and then use the mutations in your modal for setting new data and use store state in your another components like the `index.vue` that you said that you need the modal data . Here is the simplest store for just introduction to Vuex

`npm install vuex --save`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

> Now, you can access the state object as store.state, and trigger a state change with the store.commit method:

```
store.commit('increment')

console.log(store.state.count) // -> 1
```

> In order to have an access to this.$store property in your Vue components, you need to provide the created store to Vue instance. Vuex has a mechanism to "inject" the store into all child components from the root component with the store option:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
})
```

```
methods: {
  increment() {
    this.$store.commit('increment')
    console.log(this.$store.state.count)
  }
}
```

***Note*** that if you have some Axios calls or async actions, you must use the `actions` object instead of `mutations` object for defining your functions .
See below codes :

Your store schema :

```js
state : {
    APIData : null
}

mutations : {
    setAPIData(state, newData) {
        state.APIData = newData
    }
}
```

In your Vue instance :

```js
    methods: {
        post() {
            getAPI.post('api/contact/', this.form)
                .then(response => (this.data = response.data))
                .then(() => (this.$store.commit('setAPIData', this.data)))
                .catch(error => console.log(error.response))
        },
    },
```

In your another components you can access the new data with `this.APIData` as a computed property :

```js
    computed : {
        APIData(){
            return this.$store.state.APIData
        }
    }
```