# Vue.js transition between items created with v-for

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, transition

I'm cloning a flash app (http://bqgh6e.axshare.com/module.html) using vue and I need to create transitions between items created with v-for.

I've got transitions working between different components on my App.vue https://github.com/alansutherland/BodyGuard/blob/master/src/App.vue

However, within Module1.vue I'm generating slides using v-for https://github.com/alansutherland/BodyGuard/blob/master/src/components/Module1.vue

Is it possible to dynamically create router links for each item generated within the module and transition to them from one another?

Here is a hosted demo of the project so far:
https://bodyguard-9c7b0.firebaseapp.com/module-1

My current solution is to wrap the slides within a large parent and navigate them as a carousel. Not sure if this is a good solution for optimization and it doesn't feel like the vue way to do things.

I'm also running in to trouble trying to $emit back to App.vue, I'm able to pass slidePosition as a prop to the child using:

`<router-view :slidePosition="slidePosition" class="view"></router-view>`

In my module I try to $emit back using this:

```
<span v-on:click="increment" v-on:increment="incrementPosition">Start</span> 

methods: {
    increment: function () {
      this.slidePosition += 10
      this.$emit('increment')
    }
  }
```

This is based off this SO answer [vuejs update parent data from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component). Transitioning between slides using the router would be a far neater solution.

Or do I not even need to use the router? do I just use transition-groups?
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really simple solution based on this demo http://matthiashager.com/blog/image-slider-vuejs-tutorial

Rather than use v-for I just change the slide content by incrementing my slidePosition which I then use to call each item within my slide object. As a simple example, say my slides object was this:

```
slides: [
    {title: 'Slide One'},
    {title: 'Slide Two'},
    {title: 'Slide Three'},
    {title: 'Slide Four'}
  ]
```

and within data I've set `slidePosition: 0`

I can then increment the position using a button

`<button v-on:click="incrementPosition">Next</button>`

then within my methods:

```
incrementPosition: function () {
  this.slidePosition = this.slidePosition + 1
}
```

And finally in my template:

```
<h3>{{slides[slidePosition].title}}</h3>
```