# Is this TypeError linked to a wrong this.$emit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am building a component which is supposed to get an Array of Objects from the parent, display them and allow for some of the Objects to be deleted (= the child sends to the parent a new Array).

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915857/903011) was very useful to understand the child -> parent communication but I am now stuck on an error I do no understand:

```js
Vue.component('search-box', {
  template: '#search-box-template',
  props: ['who'],
  methods: {
    deleteID: function(p) {
      var user = _.filter(this.who, function(w) {
        return w.id === p.id
      })
      this.$emit('delete-id', user)
    }
  }
})
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    who: [{
      "name": "john",
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "name": "mary",
      "id": 2
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>


<div id="root">
  Hello in parent
  <search-box v-bind:who="who" v-on:delete-id="who"></search-box>
  who is: {{who}}
</div>

<template id="search-box-template">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="p in who">person: {{p.name}}, id: {{p.id}} <button v-on:click="deleteID(p)">delete</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Running this code correcly lists the users, but when trying to delete one I get in the console

```
vue.js:1739 Uncaught TypeError: fns[i].apply is not a function
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.js:1739)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (vue.js:2210)
    at VueComponent.deleteID (search.html:31)
    at Proxy.boundFn (vue.js:170)
    at click (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:9323), <anonymous>:2:164)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.js:1743)
invoker @   vue.js:1739
Vue.$emit   @   vue.js:2210
deleteID    @   search.html:31
boundFn @   vue.js:170
click   @   VM9358:2
invoker @   vue.js:1743
```

**What does this error mean? Is the `$emit` correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two problems:

1. You `_.filter` returns an arry, so you don't emit the user, but an array containing the user. That filter is also completely unnecessary, because `p`already is the user object that you intend to filter for. But that code is not the cause of the error.
2. `v-on:delete-id="who"` ere you pass an object (`who`) to the event listener, but it expects a function. That's what's raising the error.

A working version of your code would look like this:

```js
Vue.component('search-box', {
  template: '#search-box-template',
  props: ['who'],
  methods: {
    deleteID: function(p) {
      this.$emit('delete-id', p)
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    who: [{
      "name": "john",
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "name": "mary",
      "id": 2
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    handleDelete(person) {
      const index = this.who.indexOf(person)
      this.who.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>


<div id="root">
  Hello in parent
  <search-box v-bind:who="who" v-on:delete-id="handleDelete"></search-box>
  who is: {{who}}
</div>

<template id="search-box-template">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="p in who">person: {{p.name}}, id: {{p.id}} <button v-on:click="deleteID(p)">delete</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you Linus - this is excellent. I could not make out that a function (defined in the Vue instance) is expected. Now it works. I will keep my way of handling the chnage (that is - to emit an Array) as it will be populated in the component independently of the delete function (I will post an answer with that code). Thanks again, I understood a lot from your working example.

Comment: Actually I realized that I was using `_.filter()` wrong and therefore also understood your comment about sending a single user (what I wanted to do is to delete that user, not to single it out - this is corrected in the code)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Linus' excellent answer, for  the record below is my corrected code which emits and Array as when a user is deleted.

```js
Vue.component('search-box', {
  template: '#search-box-template',
  props: ['who'],
  methods: {
    deleteID: function(p) {
                var user = _.filter(this.who, function (w) {
                return w.id != p.id
            })
      this.$emit('delete-id', user)
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    who: [{
      "name": "john",
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "name": "mary",
      "id": 2
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    handleDelete(users) {
      this.who = users
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>


<div id="root">
  Hello in parent
  <search-box v-bind:who="who" v-on:delete-id="handleDelete"></search-box>
  who is: {{who}}
</div>

<template id="search-box-template">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="p in who">person: {{p.name}}, id: {{p.id}} <button v-on:click="deleteID(p)">delete</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```