# bootstrap4 tooltips not dissapears with vue.js

Tags: vue.js

after DOM item with `data-toggle="tooltip"` deleted within `vue.js`, tooltips stay hovered, like this
[image]

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="First Title" v-show="show" @click="show = !show">
  Button 1
</button>
 <button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Second Title" v-else @click="show = !show">
  Button 1
</button>
```

if I hover first button, I see tooltip "First Title" then after click I see second button and still first tooltip

how to fix it?

Comment: If you don't get any responses, you may need to share a bit more code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vuejs update parent data from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component)

Comment: `<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="First Title" v-show="show" @click="show = !show">Button 1</button>`
`<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Second Title" v-else @click="show = !show">Button 1</button>`


if I hover first button, I see tooltip "First Title"
then after click I see second button and stiil first tooltip

Comment: Still having the same issue, only solution I found was to remove overflow property from parent, did you happen to find a solution at this point?