# Event Bus to communicate between siblings. Do i need a parent and its data sent as prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-bus

I watched a video to understand how to use event bus to communicate between siblings, and in the video there was a parent with some data that was sent to the childs as a prop, then a method in one of the childs modified that prop and used an event bus to send it to the other child.

I thought, whats the point of the prop? Why cant i just use the siblings own data? And thats what i did:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

export const bus = new Vue() //Event Bus

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <ComponenteA></ComponenteA>
    <ComponenteB></ComponenteB>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ComponenteA from './components/ComponenteA.vue'
import ComponenteB from './components/ComponenteB.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components:{
    ComponenteA,
    ComponenteB
  }
}
</script>
```

**ComponentA.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 @click="changeTitle">Componente A</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from '../main'

export default {
    name: 'ComponenteA',
    data(){
        return{
            title: ''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        changeTitle(){
            this.title = 'Title emitted from A a B'
            bus.$emit('titleChanged',this.title)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**ComponentB.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Componente B -> {{title}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from '../main'

export default {
    name: 'ComponenteB',
    data(){
        return{
            title: ''
        }
    },
    created(){
        bus.$on('titleChanged', (payload) =>{
            this.title = payload
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Is there a reason for using the parent data that im failing to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the data should start in the parent and get passed down to the children is because of a couple things:

- The reactivity system in Vue.js is built around having your data in a single place (a "single source of truth"), then passing that data to wherever it is needed. Now, if only a *single* component needs the data, you'll just store that data on the component. But the data is needed in multiple components, you'll want to store it in a parent and then pass it to the children. This becomes particularly obvious if you need to start using Vuex.
- If for some reason you need to change, say, the name of the data (e.g., `pageTitle` instead of `title`), it becomes far easier to trace where the data came from if it always comes from a parent. Relying on the event bus across siblings can become rather brittle as the project grows larger.

So, in your case, the `title` should really exist in the `data` of your `App.vue` component. Each of the children would receive it as a prop. Then, if the `title` was changed, `$emit()` an event that `App.vue` is listening for. That event would change the data in `App.vue`.

Take a look at this question for more details:
[vuejs update parent data from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component)

Comment: So, in this case, ComponentA emits an event, App listen to it and updates title, which is rendered in ComponentB because its imported as a prop?