# Vue.js - Emit from grandchild slot component didn't bubble $emit event to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, slot, emit

I planned and made a modal and then created a button to close the modal window. 
I wanted to change the value of `isHomeDialog` using `$emit` as an event of the button.
However, `$emit`'s event was not delivered to "Home.vue"

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ReviewDialog
      :is-open="isHomeDialog"
      @close="closeEvent()/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ReviewDialog from '@/components/popup/dialog/ReviewDialog';
</script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    ReviewDialog
  },
  data () {
    return {
      isHomeDialog: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    closeEvent () {
      console.log('close');
      isHomeDialog = false;
    }
  }
};
```

BaseDialog.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-show="isOpen">
    <div class="mask">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="content">
      <button
        class="close"
        @click="$emit('close')">&nbsp;</button>

      <slot/>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    isOpen: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

Reviewdialog.vue

```
<template>
  <BaseDialog
    url="@/components/popup/dialog/BaseDialog"
    id="review-dialog"
    :is-open="isOpen"
    :header-text="'REVIEW'">

    <div class="warp">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
    </div>
  </BaseDialog>
</template>

<script>
import BaseDialog from '@/components/popup/dialog/BaseDialog';

export default {
  components: {
    BaseDialog
  },
  props: {
    isOpen: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
</script>
```

Home
└ BaseDialog
　└ ReviewDialog

In the above structure, I tried to send a request to BaseDialog and ReviewDialog with $emit, but it was not delivered to Home.
Is there any way to send $ emit to its parent component other than requesting it with $root.$emit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BaseDialog` emits the `close` event to its parent, `ReviewDialog`, which is not listening for it.  So you need to listen in `ReviewDialog`, and re-emit the event to `Home`:

```html
<BaseDialog
    url="@/components/popup/dialog/BaseDialog"
    id="review-dialog"
    :is-open="isOpen"
    :header-text="'REVIEW'"
    @close="$emit('close')"> <-- This line is new -->
```

Another way to do this is to have `ReviewDialog` pass all its listeners down:

```html
<BaseDialog
    url="@/components/popup/dialog/BaseDialog"
    id="review-dialog"
    :is-open="isOpen"
    :header-text="'REVIEW'"
    v-on="$listeners"> <-- This line is new -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your help. $listeners is an event handler, but it seems to receive and pass the event of $emit of sub-component. is right?

Comment: You're welcome. `$listeners` contains all of the things listening to the component, it's a special syntax that passes them all to a child component

Answer (score 0):

Since  two-way binding is deprecated in Vue2 + child cannot mutate props directly

Likely another approach `custom component with v-model`

I put reference below:
[vuejs update parent data from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component)