# Vue 3 not hiding not toggling in parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a showUpdate boolean in my Profile parent component, which I'm passing to my update-profile child component, whenever I toggle it back from the update-profile the Profile component doesn't show the button again.

This is from my Profile Parent Component

```
<button
   v-if="!showUpdate"
   v-on:click="showUpdate = !showUpdate"
   class="btn btn-warning m-3"
   >
   <span class="cil-contrast btn-icon mr-2"></span> Primary
</button>
    data() {
        return {
            showUpdate: false,
        };
    },
```

This is from my Update-Profile Component

```
<button
    v-on:click="showUpdate = !showUpdate"
    class="btn btn-warning m-3"
    >
      <span class="cil-contrast btn-icon mr-2"></span> Cancel
    </button>
props: ["company", "showUpdate"],
```

Whenever I click the button on my Update-Profile the button on my Profile doesen't render again and not showing.

Comment: At the moment your Update-Profile component is mutating the showUpdate prop. This is an anti-pattern, and might be the cause of your problems. Check out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow for more info on this

Comment: So is there no way to update both props?

Comment: you need to emit from update-profile component inorder to handle/view changes in parent component

Comment: Can I have some reference on how to do this? I'm new to Vue.js and would like to learn more.

Comment: @kgcusi have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915857/7970660. Essentially, you want to emit an event, and then the component that contains the update-profile component will, when it receives this event, change the data