# Vue 3 - Two-Way Data Binding Trouble With Child Component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm having trouble getting two-way data binding to work in Vue 3 between a parent component and its child component, which is a form.

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <h5>{{ record.title }}</h5>
  <ChildForm v-model:record="record"></ChildForm>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data() {
    record: undefined
  },
  created() {
    //code to fetch record
    this.$data.record = new Record(responseJson);
  },
  watch: {
    record: function(newRecord, oldRecord) {
      alert("change detected!");
      //perform appropriate logic when record is changed in child
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**child.vue**

```
<template>
  <InputText v-model="record.title"></InputText>
  <InputText v-model="record.description"></InputText>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: {
    record: {
      type: Object as () => RecordModel
    }
  },
  emits: ["update:record"]
}
```

If I change the title in the ChildForm's title input box, the parent accurately reflects the change in the h5 header. But, the watch function never gets fired.

What do I have to do to get the parent's watch method to fire when the child changes the model object's values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes:

1. You're modifying the prop directly, which is frowned upon, and never technically emitting `update:record` so the v-model is in essence, useless.  If you were emitting, then the watch would fire as you would expect.  If you want an example on how to do this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40915857/5508690) that shows the jist of it for vue2, you'll just need to modify it to use the new `update:prop` event names.
2. If you want to keep modifying the prop directly, then you don't need the `v-model:record` at all.   Just use `:record="record"` and make the watcher deep

```
watch: {
    record: {
        handler(newRecord, oldRecord) {
            alert("change detected!");
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "modifying the prop directly", do you mean how I assign v-model="record.title" in the child? But regardless, I'm going to give that answer's suggestion a try.

Comment: I'm confused how the linked solution maps to mine- the linked answer isn't using the props of an object., but just a simple value (like a string or number)

Answer (score 1):

The answer Steven B linked to was correct but it took some work to adapt to Vue 3 and my case:

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <h5>{{ record.title }}</h5>
  <ChildForm v-model:record="record" v-on:update:record="parentRecordUpdate"></ChildForm>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data() {
    record?: undefined
  },
  created() {
    //code to fetch record
    this.$data.record = new Record(responseJson);
  },
  methods: {
    parentRecordUpdate() {
      alert("change detected!");
      //perform appropriate logic when record is changed in child
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**child.vue**

```
<template>
  <InputText v-bind:value="record.title" @input="childUpdateRecord('title', $event.target.value)"></InputText>
  <InputText v-bind:value="record.status" @input="childUpdateRecord('status', $event.target.value)"></InputText>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: {
    record: {
      type: Object as () => RecordModel
    }
  },
  emits: ["update:record"],
  methods: {
    childUpdateRecord(field: string, value: string) {
      //Update with whatever happened in the InputText box
      this.$props.record.setAttribute(field, value);
      //calling $emit triggers the parent's update method
      this.$emit('update:record', this.$props.record);
    }
  }
}
```