# Vuejs - exange informations between non parent-child components

Tags: javascript, html, web, vue.js, components

I'm trying to exchange informations between two VueJs components.

Here is the situation :

Component A is the main component.
B and C are into A, and D is into C.

I want to change a variable value of component D, from component B.

I've see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925841/how-can-i-share-data-between-non-parent-child-components-in-vue) that if the components are using the same root component, we could done a broadcast from a first component to the root, then after get the broadcasted data from the root to a second component.
But in my case, my component D is not directly in the root and deeper in the "components tree"... So, i tried and it would seem that this does not work.

What is the easiest way or more elegant way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share data between non parent-child components in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925841/how-can-i-share-data-between-non-parent-child-components-in-vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this I'd use an Eventbus as described in the vue documentation; a blank Vue object for passing information agnostically.

```
window.EventBus = new Vue();
```

Then in your component that receives data, you'd create an event.

```
mounted: function () {
    EventBus.$on('name', function (data) {
        // Do something with the data
    });
}
```

Finally, in the component that sends data, you need to call that function.

```
methods: {
    someFunction: function () {
        EventBus.$emit('name', data);
    }
}
```

You can create a prototype link that provides access to the EventBus object for ease of use.

```
Vue.prototype.$eventBus = window.EventBus
```

Which you can access by using `this.$eventBus.$on` or `this.$eventBus.$emit` as seen in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wjmrgcc/).

Comment: Thank you ! I'm using the Vue-cli, so i don't use the same syntax than you (xxx.xx = new Vue ();... I'm starting in vuejs and web development, and i don't know how to use your help into my components. Can you help me ?

Comment: In fact, I'm using single page components, and i don't know how to use what you said to me in my specific template.

Comment: OK I got it. When using Single Page component template, i created a eventBus.js file, including 'import Vue from vue\n let bus = new Vue()\n export default bus' and so if i need to emit or listen an event from my eventBus, i juste need to "import bus from '@/path/eventBus' " then use it like this: 'bus.$on('myEvent', myVariable)'

Comment: Sorry been pretty busy this last week. If you're using Components I normally turn it into a plugin. that way you can use `Vue.use(plugin)` in your main javascript then the EventBus object will be accessible from all of your components.

Comment: Ok, very interesting ! So, in that way, how can i call this new plugin ?